# How can I access the file I uploaded after uploading it using the BlueImp jQuery FileUpload?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-web-api, blueimp

I am migrating from an ASP.NET app that is using Session to an angular/MVC app that is not.

Here is the existing scenario:
A user uploads an XML file to the server, upon which we run a validation routine against the XML. If there are any warnings, we present a dialog to the user asking whether he/she wants to cancel or continue.  If the user opts to continue, on the server we pull the XML file out of Session and continue processing.

In our new app, we don't have access to session, and I'm kicking around various ways of handling this.

I'm wondering if there is any way to re-upload the file using the BlueImp jquery fileupload widget (without the user's interaction for the re-upload).

My implementation is not set in stone, but here is what I'm working on at the moment:

I have 2 different webAPI methods - the 1st is the initial upload.  The 2nd is the 'continue, I approve the warnings' step.

I've been playing around with the various callbacks available in the jquery fileupload.  I was hoping to do something like: in the send callback, make the initial send, then block until we receive the server response, then provide a dialog to the user, then if the user clicks continue, change the URL on the fileupload widget, then call send again.

Thoughts?

Edited to add:
I am trying to leverage the chunked file functionality - I thought if I set the uploaded bytes to 0, it would send the whole thing again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `MemoryCache` as a simple replacement for your session:

On the server, store the uploaded file in a `MemoryCache`, assign a GUID and return the GUID to the client. When the client approves the warning, simply send another request with the GUID only and then continue to process the file.

Uploading the file a second time is not a good idea for at least two reasons:

1. You don't know if the file was changed, so you would have to check the whole thing again.
2. You can save bandwidth (especially important for mobile applications) if you only send it once.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I like the idea of returning the GUID, the only issue I see with this approach is that I wouldn't know when to expire it.  

I came up with a solution that I will share below - the #1 concern you raise is not an issue for me; I am sure the file hasn't changed, because there is no user interaction involved in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most elegant solution, but this is what I came up with and it worked for me.  It's an angularJS directive; here is the (abridged) link function:

link: function (scope, iElement, iAttr)
               {

```
               var continueUpload = function ()
               {
                   iElement.fileupload({
                                   url: 'myUrl_continue',
                                   dataType: 'json'
                               });

                               var filesList = iElement[0].files;

                               iElement.fileupload('send', { files: filesList });
               };

               iElement.fileupload({
                   url: 'myUrl',
                   dataType: 'json',
                   add: function (e, data)
                   {                        
                       var jqXHR = data.submit()
                       .success(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR)
                       {
                           if ((result == 1) || (result == 2))
                           {
                               Confirm(msg, scope, function () { continueUpload(); }, function () { doNothingRightNow(); });                                  
                           }
                       })
                   }
               });
           }
```

Hope this helps someone.